# Cannot connect Monster motor shield with Beaglebone black

Tags: hardware, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, motordriver

I am trying to connect beaglebone black with monster motor shield (VNH2SP30) from sparkfun.
I have given 12v supply to the power supply, 2 motors are connected to it (A1 A2 and B1 B2) and i want to control it using pwm.
the code that i have written is in python but i am convinced that the problem is more of interfacing than of coding. 
As for pin connections are concerned, they are as follows
`P8_7 to pin 2 
P8_8 to pin 3 
P8_9 to pin 4 
P8_10 to pin 5` 
for pwm 
`P8_13 to pin 9
P8_19 to pin 10`
and GND pin is connected as well

Beagleboard is getting power from USB 5v 2A. 
I am thinking the problem is regarding serial communication between these 2 boards and the baud rate between them. Please correct me if i am wrong and provide me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect Monster Motor Shield with Beaglebone even if you set the UART properly along with the baud rate.

It is purely designed for arduino only, so if anyone is encountering similar problem the best motor driver is [Dual DC Motor Driver from Robokits](https://robokits.co.in/motor-drives-drivers/dual-dc-motor-driver-20a?gclid=CjwKCAjwmq3kBRB_EiwAJkNDpxeSl-7K9UP-Q-T0LG_oNMWyF4Z6a5fL9m5T4Z4jgqe6JF_vR8krbRoCLlQQAvD_BwE)

**EDIT :**  The reason for such behavior was in the basic understanding of the electronics of Beaglebone, it provides logical 5v to the Monstor Motor Sheild which is less than what is actually required and thus it was not able to start up